ZFS resilver of 2 disks: serial or parallel?
I have 2 faulty disks in my zraid2 setup, and I'd need to understand whether it's better to replace and resilver them one by one or at the same time. My main concern is that I cannot afford loosing another disk before at least one faulty one is resilvered; is it preferable to go first for a single disk to minimize the resilver load (and the breakage probability during the process) or to go for both at the same time (to minimize the overall recovery time)?
Sorry for the dumb question but it's the first time I'm facing such a situation.
Edit: this is the pool configuration in the degraded/faulty state
$ zpool status -L
 pool: storage
state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to persistent errors.
       Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue functioning in a
       degraded state.
action: Replace the faulted device, or use 'zpool clear' to mark the device
       repaired.
 scan: scrub repaired 1.84M in 1 days 10:44:58 with 0 errors on Sun Jun  9 05:23:05 2024
config:

   NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
   storage     DEGRADED     0     0     0
     raidz2-0  DEGRADED     0     0     0
       sda     FAULTED     74     0     0  too many errors
       sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sde     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdh     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdg     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdi     FAULTED     73     0     0  too many errors
       sdk     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdj     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdm     ONLINE       0     0     0
     raidz2-1  ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdl     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdn     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdo     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdp     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdr     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdq     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sds     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdt     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdu     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdw     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdy     ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdv     ONLINE       0     0     0
   logs
     nvme0n1   ONLINE       0     0     0
   cache
     sdz       ONLINE       0     0     0
     sdx       ONLINE       0     0     0


Depends on the setup. Can you show the current zpool status?

I added the pool status to the first post. Anyway I tried to replace just one disk, and when I booted the machine ZFS automatically started the resilvering of the remaining faulty one. Resilver has failed because of new errors so now I started the manual resilver of the new disk and I am proceeding sequentially. Still I'd be interested in understanding which resilver strategy would be the best, at least theoretically.

You may not even have an actual failed disk. Which OS is this? You can run a zpool clear storage to clear those errors.

I'm on Rocky Linux 9. I think at least one disk is really faulty since after reboot it showed no errors and then error count started rising and now it's FAULTED again.

Take a look at dmesg output.

Once you confirm that the disks are actually faulted, check the health of other drives to ensure you can proceed safely. Sequential is the best strategy.
I had a recent RAIDZ2 failure where two disks were failed, and a third was incrementing checksum and read errors. That was a more delicate surgery that required careful sequential recovery.
